# Linq Take doing extra passes through collection

Tags: c#, linq

I was trying to better understand the function composition in linq and to that effect I wrote code like this:

```
var x = Enumerable.Range(1, 10);

var result = x.Select(AddFive)
              .Where(FilterEvens)
              .Take(1);

result.ToList();
```

Where the AddFive and FilterEvens methods are defined as below:

```
int AddFive(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Adding five");
    return n+5;
}

bool FilterEvens(int n)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Filtering evens");
    return n%2 == 0;
}
```

If I take 1 and run it, I get the following result which is what I would expect:

> Adding five 
>   Filtering evens

If I try to take 2 or 5 however, I get:

> Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five 
>   Filtering evens

And:

> Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens
>   Adding five
>   Filtering evens

In other words it looks like the Take is going further than it needs to in the collection. Is this is a bug? (I'm guessing it's not.) If it's not, is there some good reason why it's implemented this way?

Comment: It works just as expected. Try doing `.Take(1)` on a `.Range(2,10)`, you'll see two items being projected and filtered. :) `Take` will take at most as many items as you specify from the sequence *after all previous transformations*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Take` is not going further. It keeps iterating until it finds as many numbers as you want.Since you have a filtering, not all numbers are returned because some of them do not satify the condition.So, you see the message for each number projected by `Select` and filtered by `Where.`

For example in case of `Take(2)`:

```
Select returns 6 to where - it's returned 
Select returns 7 to where - not returned
Select returns 8 to where - returned
```

That's why you see the message three times